# how can i restrict any special characters entered in the textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

How can I restrict any special characters entered in the textbox?
I have a textbox where the user can enter in the textbox to validate if the url exists in the db. Before I hit the db I want to make sure there is no special characters entered in the textbox

for an example if some user try to enter something like:
 `)(*&<>&*^&*^&*$%#!@#$http://www.cnn.com!@#$%^&*()`

Before they paste or type the url with special characters how can I not allowed in the textbox?

The only expection to this is: `&` (ampersand) is allowed if it is in between the url something like this:

```
http://cnn.com/news/latest.html&id=1
```

Comment: Similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150973/filtering-what-characters-can-be-added-to-a-text-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer is to just make a method to strip characters on the client side.

```
$('#myTextBox').keyup(function()
{
     var santizedValue = '';
     for(var j = 0; j < this.value.length; j++)
        if(this.value[j].toLower() == 'a' || this.value[j].toLower() == 'b' ... )
           sanitizedValue += this.value[j];

        //Alternatively; convert the character to integer and check the ASCII range for a-z + &

     this.value = sanitizedValue;
});
```

You make a similar method on your server (just in case the client doesnt have javascript or defeats the script).

Comment: This approach fails, when user copy & paste a string having some special characters in it...

Answer (score 1):

Use the textbox's `KeyPress` event. In the handler, run the regular expression you want to validate against the `e.KeyChar`, and if it finds an invalid character, set `e.Handled` to `true`. This will prevent the character from being entered in the box.

If you want to test the entire text, you can concatenate the new character and current `Text` property, and run an expression against that.

Alternatively, use the `Validating` event to test the entire input when validation is needed.

**Edit:** In response to [the link garykindel posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150973/filtering-what-characters-can-be-added-to-a-text-box), `KeyPress` is going to be a better option than `TextChanged` or a MaskedTextBox since the former fires events before undoing the change, as well as messes with a user's input position, and a MaskedTextBox too constrictive for something like black-listed characters.

Comment: This is only valid for a client application; doing a post back on each keyup on the client is suicide.