# Eliminate user input of single quote for every field in every form in a project

Tags: vb.net

using  VB.net and Visual studio is there a way to globally (across all fields in all forms in a project) prevent a user from entering a single quote character into a field.  I'm thinking some sort of modification of the keypress event, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Currently I am currently using the ADDHANDLER, ADDRESSOF technique to assign this special code to a particular field, and I guess I could do a loop over all my contained controls on a particular form and assign the keypress code, but if there is a way to do it once without repeating the code on each form that would be great.  Any hints graciously accepted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about a regex? [Stripping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150973/filtering-what-characters-can-be-added-to-a-text-box) or [converting to escape character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) on submit?

Would it be possible to pass an array where TextBox1 is TextBox1,Textbox2, etc. Obviously you would need to edit the expression if you only need to strip the single quote. This for all non alphabet characters. I don't do much with vb.net but thought this might be helpful.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As           System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
StripNonAlphabetCharacters(TextBox1)
End Sub

Public Sub StripNonAlphabetCharacters(ByVal input As TextBox)
' pattern matches any character that is NOT A-Z (allows upper and lower case alphabets)
Dim rx As New Regex("[^a-zA-Z]")
If (rx.IsMatch(input.Text)) Then
    Dim startPosition As Integer = input.SelectionStart - 1
    input.Text = rx.Replace(input.Text, "")
    input.SelectionStart = startPosition
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to create a derived TextBox and use that instead of the standard textbox.

```
Public Class NoQuoteTextBox
    Inherits TextBox
    Public Sub New()
        AddHandler MyBase.KeyPress, AddressOf Handler
    End Sub

    Public Sub Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)
        If e.KeyChar = "'" Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Build your project then the NoQuoteTextBox (or whatever you decide to call it) will appear in the Toolbox in the Designer:

[image: Toolbox with custom control]

Use this new control instead of the standard textbox and it will handle the single quote for you.